# How to grep a multiple text line section from a beginning text pattern to an ending pattern?

Tags: linux, grep

For example text below , in Linux, how to get the section below from the "will be installed" to the text before "Suggested packages".

```
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
   python3-decorator python3-simplegeneric
Suggested packages:
  ipython3-notebook ipython3-qtconsole python3-zmq
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ipython3 python3-decorator python3-simple-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

And the output to get is simply " ipython3-notebook ipython3-qtconsole python3-zmq" , WITHOUT the beginning and ending pattern.

Comment: [`grep` regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html)

Comment: @NathaneilCapital, have you tried anything?  It's a very simple problem, and a google for grep will give you some examples.

Comment: This question is unclear.  It should ***show*** the desired outcome/result, inasmuch as the OP's informal *description* of it seems to be giving rise to multiple interpretations. The way I interpret it, it is not a very simple problem, and @DavidPostill's link is not particularly useful.

Comment: @G-Man It's a starting point for the OP to figure out what he's trying to do ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Added the intended result, appreciate if you can help

Comment: @finding the pattern is easy, But here the question is to exclude two patterns from the output. I did checked myself online, not sure why it is simple, why not share your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` rather than `grep`:

```
$ gsed -n '/The following extra packages will be installed:/{:a;n;/Suggested packages:/q;p;ba}' text
```

When the line containing the text `The following extra packages will be installed`, the `sed` editing script will create a label called `a` (to jump back to later) and then read the next line (`n`). If that line contains the text `Suggested packages:` the script will terminate (`q`), otherwise it prints the line (`p`) and branches back to the label previously created (`ba`) which reads the next line, etc.